# Unable to load profile image and header background from URL

Tags: android, imageview, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) step by step but when I want to load profile image and header background nothing displayed. I added internet permission and wifi is on and initialized drawerimageloader. What could the problem be?

Main activity:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IProfile;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {;

Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();

  AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike 
  Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon(Uri.
  parse("https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/887462?v=3&s=460"))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new 
  AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, 
  boolean currentProfile) {
                   return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

  new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .build();

  ImageView view = headerResult.getHeaderBackgroundView();
  Glide.with(this).load("www.api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-
  bg.jpg").into(view);
  }

  }
```

custom activity:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.AbstractDrawerImageLoader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.DrawerImageLoader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.util.DrawerUIUtils;

/**
 * Created by mikepenz on 27.03.15.
 *
 */
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    /*
    //initialize and create the image loader logic
    DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) 
   {

   Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder)
   .into(imageView);
        }
        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
        }
    });
    */

    //initialize and create the image loader logic
    DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder, 
   String tag) {
   Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri)
  .placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Glide.clear(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable placeholder(Context ctx, String tag) {
            //define different placeholders for different imageView targets
            //default tags are accessible via the DrawerImageLoader.Tags
            if (DrawerImageLoader.Tags.PROFILE.name().equals(tag)) {
                return DrawerUIUtils.getPlaceHolder(ctx);
            } else if 
 (DrawerImageLoader.Tags.ACCOUNT_HEADER.name().equals(tag)) {
                return new IconicsDrawable(ctx).iconText(" 
 ").backgroundColorRes(com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.R.color.primary)
.sizeDp(56);
            } else if ("customUrlItem".equals(tag)) {
                return new IconicsDrawable(ctx).iconText(" 
").backgroundColorRes(R.color.md_red_500).sizeDp(56);
            }

            //we use the default one for
            //DrawerImageLoader.Tags.PROFILE_DRAWER_ITEM.name()

            return super.placeholder(ctx, tag);
        }
    });
}
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ir.techend.yusof.ghaza">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: mikepenz tutorial

Comment: am I supposed to know where that is?? can you put up a reference in. your question..... nm -> u did

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i have no error

Comment: were in that code do (from GitHub) does he set the header background or the profile image? you need to really start there.

Comment: are you storing images in some sort of db? firebase/parse-server if not, just store the image in drawable and set the image view that way. otherwise, look into imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)

Comment: as you can see in this link : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_sample_dark_toolbar.xml everything is done in background

Comment: glide will take care of caching

Comment: thats an XML file... doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: my problem is solved. i have some network problem. and you should add this line before your url : https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#load-images-via-url . thanks mike for your awesome library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the duplicated

```
new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();
```

Which you have in your `MainActivity`, You must only `.build()` one `Drawer` (and in some cases `.append()` another one)

The code of the `Drawer` will make sure not 2 `DrawerLayout`'s are inflated.

In addition I checked the url for the header image. This one does not exist.  (http://www.api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg returns a 404)

Comment: hey mike, i had network problem and not added init image loader. now i'm ok. thanks for your library ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library for that

```
 Picasso.with(YourActivityName.this).load(url_img).into(imageView);
```

and in your gradle dependency put

```
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```